# Pattern-specific make variable based on the highest level target name

Tags: make, gnu-make

### Goal

In the usual case of a target (mother target) calling another target (child target) as prerequisite, I'd like to assign a pattern-specific variable (see the [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern_002dspecific.html#Pattern_002dspecific)) with the following conditions:

- The value of the variable is based on the mother target.
- The child target needs this variable

### Context

I can reduce my usecase to the following. I will be using a target-specific variable instead of a pattern-specific one for simplicity (the problem is the same). Here is the Makefile:

```
mother-target: VAR = Var-$@
mother-target: child-target

child-target:
    echo VAR=$(VAR)
```

`make` will output `VAR=Var-child-target`, and I'd like it to output `VAR=Var-mother-target`.

**Question:** How to refer to the name of the target defining the variable?
The `@`automatic variable seems to always resolve to the "last" target in the chain.

**Attempts**:

- `VAR` as a simply expanded variable, i.e. `mother-target: VAR := Var-$@`. But `$@` is empty.
- Declare `VAR` private so that it's not inherited doesn't suit my use case: the child-target needs the variable.

The real case is with a pattern-specific variable where having the name of the target resolved would actually be useful (i.e. `%-target: VAR = Var-$@`)

Comment: I don't think you can achieve anything like that without a recursive make invocation, in which case you would not need pattern-specific variables at all.

Comment: @mosvy You mean recursively call `make` specifying the variable when calling it? I.e. 
`mother-target: make VAR=Var-$@ child-target`
The real Makefile is much more convoluted and that would probably bring other problems. And that's less elegant, for what it's worth...

Comment: Everybody's doing it like that. But feel free to explore alternative approaches. Your current approach will not work, in any case.

Comment: @mosvy Thank you. Could you recommend some reading about why it doesn't work? I can't find anything about the internals in the manual. I.e. why can't `@` be resolved at definition time of the target-specific variable?

Comment: I actually find that target/pattern-specific variables are a very nice way to avoid recursive make calls in most of the cases, but obviously not in mine...

Comment: "[Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables) [like `$@`] ... have values computed afresh for each rule
that is executed ... It's very important that you recognize the limited scope in which
automatic variable values are available: they only have values within
the recipe ... A common mistake is attempting to use `$@`
within the prerequisites list; __this will not work__.

Comment: "... However, there is a
special feature of GNU 'make', [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html#Secondary-Expansion), which will allow automatic variable values to be used in
prerequisite lists." -- except that `.SECONDEXPANSION` will not help you here ;-(

Comment: @mosvy Yes but in that context, the variable assignment is not a prerequisite. This is why I'd like to understand the context of target-specific variables better.
Indeed one could imagine secondary expansion to be useful here: `@` would be expanded once at definition time, and a second time at "execution" time, so that `$@` would give `mother-target` and `$$@` `child-target`. But an in-between target could never be resolved...
Thanks a lot for your time. If I investigate further, I'll keep this post updated.